# PowerBI - DAX Column Name - Square Brackets

Tags: syntax, ssas, powerbi, dax

The DAX query below returns the column name of [ID] instead of ID when querying to an SSAS.

Is this an injection error? How can I remove the brackets from the column names?

```
EVALUATE(
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
    'TableName',
    "ID", 'TableName'[ID]  
    )  
)
```

Comment: Are you querying from SSMS?

Comment: I'm querying from Power BI Desktop to a SSAS connection.